# Как реализовать линии перечеркивающие блок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

div::after,
div::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

div::after {
  left: 0px;
}

div::before {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>44</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

div::after,
div::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: yellow;  
}

div::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-50%);
  left: 0px;
}

div::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>44</div>
```

Comment: а можно только через одно псевдо? другое занято)

Answer (score 1):

### Обдумайте вариант использования SVG + CSS.

В SVG легко создавать различные формы  простые, как у вас, и более сложные.
Так же вы получаете адаптивность и максимальную поддержку браузерами.
При необходимости если это вектор, то легко создать различные анимации

```css
.shadow-3 {
  background: #e8e8e8;
 width:35vw;
 height:auto;
}
svg  {
  background: white;
    margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow-3">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  version="1.1" id="svg6"  viewBox="0 0 200 200">
   <text xml:space="preserve"  x="63.6" y="119.5" id="text836" font-style="normal" font-variant="normal" font-weight="400" font-stretch="normal" font-size="64" font-family="Berlin Sans FB" fill="#7A8D91" ><tspan id="tspan834" x="63.6" y="119.5">44</tspan></text>
  
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="180" height="180" rx="18" fill="none" stroke="#E6E5EA" stroke-width="4" id="rect4"/>
  <path d="M20.3 20.3 178 178.8" id="path830" fill="none" stroke="#E6E5EA" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round"  stroke-dasharray="none"/>
  <path d="M178 20.3 20.3 178.8" id="path832" fill="none" stroke="#E6E5EA" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round"  stroke-dasharray="none"/>
 
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Варианты анимации

Это не требовалось в  вопросе. Поэтому это не ответ, а бонусный пост.

***Ответ ниже***

### Анимация SVG

- *Анимация линий зачеркивания*

Основана на  изменении параметров `stroke-dasharray` от изменения значения максимального пробела `stroke-dasharray="0,223.5"` до нулевого пробела и максимальной черты `stroke-dasharray="223.5,0"`

В команде анимации это записано в `values=""` вот так:

```
<animate id="anP1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.5s" 
  values="0,223.5;223.5,0" fill="freeze" restart="never" />
```

**анимация после клика**

```css
.shadow-3 {
  background: #e8e8e8;
 width:35vw;
 
}
svg  {
  background: white;
   margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 4px 10px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow-3">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  version="1.1"   width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
   <text xml:space="preserve"  x="63.6" y="119.5" id="text836" font-style="normal" font-variant="normal" font-weight="400" font-stretch="normal" font-size="64" font-family="Berlin Sans FB" fill="#7A8D91" ><tspan id="tspan834" x="63.6" y="119.5">44</tspan></text>
                   <!-- полная длина линии  688.36 -->
  <rect id="rect4" x="10" y="10" width="180" height="180" rx="18" fill="none" stroke="#E6E5EA" stroke-width="4">
  </rect>    
   
                    <!-- полная длина линии  223.5 -->
  <path id="path1" d="M20.3 20.3 178 178.8"  fill="none" stroke="#E6E5EA" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round"  stroke-dasharray="0,223.5">
    <animate id="anP1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.5s" values="0,223.5;223.5,0" fill="freeze" restart="never" />
   </path> 
       <!-- полная длина линии  223.5 -->
  <path id="path2" d="M178 20.3 20.3 178.8"  fill="none" stroke="#E6E5EA" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round"  stroke-dasharray="0,223.5">
    <animate id="anP2" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="anP1.end+0.2s" dur="0.5s" values="0,223.5;223.5,0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"/>
   </path> 
 
</svg>
</div>
```

- *Анимация контура квадрата и линий зачеркивания*

Последовательные анимации (друг за другом) реализованы логическим цепочками в `begin`

`begin="anRect.end+0.2s"` буквально - когда заканчивается анимация прямоугольника, через паузу в `0.2s` начнется анимация рисования линии.

```css
.shadow-3 {
  background: #e8e8e8;
 width:35vw;
 
}
svg  {
  background: white;
  
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 4px 10px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow-3">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  version="1.1"   width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
   <text xml:space="preserve"  x="63.6" y="119.5" id="text836" font-style="normal" font-variant="normal" font-weight="400" font-stretch="normal" font-size="64" font-family="Berlin Sans FB" fill="#7A8D91" ><tspan id="tspan834" x="63.6" y="119.5">44</tspan></text>
                   <!-- полная длина линии  688.36 -->
  <rect id="rect4" x="10" y="10" width="180" height="180" rx="18" fill="none" stroke="#E6E5EA" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="0,688.36" >
     <animate id="anRect"  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" values="0,688.36;688.36,0" fill="freeze" restart="never" />
 </rect>     
   
                    <!-- полная длина линии  223.5 -->
  <path id="path1" d="M20.3 20.3 178 178.8"  fill="none" stroke="#E6E5EA" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round"  stroke-dasharray="0,223.5">
    <animate id="anP1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="anRect.end+0.2s" dur="0.5s" values="0,223.5;223.5,0" fill="freeze" />
   </path> 
       <!-- полная длина линии  223.5 -->
  <path id="path2" d="M178 20.3 20.3 178.8"  fill="none" stroke="#E6E5EA" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round"  stroke-dasharray="0,223.5">
    <animate id="anP2" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="anP1.end+0.2s" dur="0.5s" values="0,223.5;223.5,0" fill="freeze" />
   </path>
 </svg>
</div>
```

### Вариант анимации CSS

Анимация зачеркивания при наведении курсора

```css
.shadow-3 {
  background: #e8e8e8;
 width:35vw;
 
}
svg  {
  background: white;
  
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 4px 10px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
#path1,#path2 {
stroke:#E6E5EA;
 stroke-width:4;
 stroke-linecap:round; 
stroke-dasharray:0,223.5; 
}
#svg1:hover   #path1 {
stroke-dasharray:0,223.5;
animation:draw 0.5s forwards;
}
@keyframes draw {
to {stroke-dasharray:223.5,0;}
}
#svg1:hover   #path2 {
stroke-dasharray:0,223.5;
animation:draw 0.5s  forwards 0.5s;
}
@keyframes draw2 {
to {stroke-dasharray:223.5,0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow-3">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  version="1.1"   width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
   <text xml:space="preserve"  x="63.6" y="119.5" id="text836" font-style="normal" font-variant="normal" font-weight="400" font-stretch="normal" font-size="64" font-family="Berlin Sans FB" fill="#7A8D91" ><tspan id="tspan834" x="63.6" y="119.5">44</tspan></text>
                   <!-- полная длина линии  688.36 -->
  <rect id="rect4" x="10" y="10" width="180" height="180" rx="18" fill="none" stroke="#E6E5EA" stroke-width="4">
  </rect>    
   
                    <!-- полная длина линии  223.5 -->
  <path id="path1" d="M20.3 20.3 178 178.8" stroke="red" >
    
   </path> 
       <!-- полная длина линии  223.5 -->
  <path id="path2" d="M178 20.3 20.3 178.8" >
    <animate id="anP2" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="anP1.end+0.2s" dur="0.5s" values="0,223.5;223.5,0" fill="freeze" />
   </path> 
 
</svg>
</div>
```